# Looking for an erratum (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview

**Note:** Since what I am asking about below touches on a potentially controversial subject, let me emphasize that I am only asking for a specific reference, and I am not asking for a discussion of the controversy itself, or even for other references besides the specific one I'm asking about.

---

Some years ago, I recall seeing an erratum that I would now like to cite, but I'm having trouble finding it because I don't remember enough details about it.

What I remember for sure is that the entire content of the erratum was to assert that the use of "Taniyama–Shimura" in the original article should be replaced by "Shimura–Taniyama."  I'm also nearly certain that there was nothing else on the same page of the journal/periodical in which this erratum appeared.

I *think* that the erratum appeared in the *Notices of the American Mathematical Society*, but after a few minutes of futile searching, I'm beginning to doubt myself.

Does anyone recognize what I'm talking about?

Comment: You're looking for Ribet's Erratum to "Galois Representations and Modular Forms".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Sofie Verbeek for the answer.  The reference is

> Erratum to "Galois Representations and Modular Forms" by Kenneth A. Ribet, *Bulletin (New Series) of the American Mathematical Society* **33** (1996), p. 43.

Comment: Freely accessible: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1996-33-01/S0273-0979-96-00647-7/S0273-0979-96-00647-7.pdf